# Working With Multiple Loops Referencing Elements Of Lists

Tags: python, list, loops, concurrency, element

I've made a little sample of the error I'm facing . What i actually need the code to do is for every key to pick two quests and print it alongside the key . When i run the code at first it seemed to be working then does not . Could anyone help . This is the output and the code sample

Actual Output

```
1 + 1 head
1 + 1 head
2 + 2 head
1 + 1 head
2 + 2 leg
1 + 1 head
2 + 2 nose
1 + 1 head
2 + 2 tail
1 + 1 head
list index out of range
pop from empty list
list index out of range
list index out of range
list index out of range
list index out of range
list index out of range
list index out of range
```

Expected Output

```
1 + 1 head
2 + 2 head
3 + 3 leg
4 + 4 leg
5 + 5 nose
6 + 6 nose
7 + 7 tail
8 + 8 tail
```

Code

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
keys = ['head','leg','nose','tail']
quest = ['1 + 1','2 + 2','3 + 3','4 + 4','5 + 5','6 + 6','7 + 7' , '8 + 8']
count = []
def solve(i):
    try:
       for h in quest():
         if len(count) != 2:
            q = keys[0]
            print(i,q)
            count.append(q.strip())
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
t = 2
def run():
    thread = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=t) as exe:
        for i in quest:
          threads.append(exe.submit(solve,i))
run
```

Comment: There's a call to an unknown function `quests()` in your posted code. What is that function doing?

Comment: @blorgon didnt notice that meant to write quest

Comment: Okay, but you're still using function call syntax, and `quest` is a `list` object...

Comment: @blorgon so how do i got about it ?

Comment: Go about what? Iterating over a `list`?

Comment: No modifying my code to get the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> keys = ['head', 'leg', 'nose', 'tail']
>>> quest = ['1 + 1', '2 + 2', '3 + 3', '4 + 4', '5 + 5', '6 + 6', '7 + 7', '8 + 8']
>>> doubled_keys= sum([[*t] for t in zip(keys, keys)], [])
>>> pairs = [*zip(quest, doubled_keys)]
>>> for q, k in pairs:
...     print(q, k)
...
1 + 1 head
2 + 2 head
3 + 3 leg
4 + 4 leg
5 + 5 nose
6 + 6 nose
7 + 7 tail
8 + 8 tail
```

Comment: It works but you took out the Threading code , the quests  are sometimes over a lot so the work will need to be done  faster . Can include the threading in your answer